# Change plugin name on WordPress repo

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, svn

Months ago i have created a simple WordPress plugin that shows Latest post with thumbnails, but as the plugin name includes the word "Ads" it has been a report from a user that the plguin assets are being blocked by AdBlock, so i will need to change the name to something else.

I have googled about it but i couldnt find any usefull info.

Does anyone know how to change the plugin name without having to upload it to WordPress repo as a new plugin?

Answer (score 5):

You can change the name of your plugin, you just can't change the url slug of your plugin.  Meaning, if you initially added a plugin to the repo and it was called "Posts With Ad Thumbnails" your url would be: `https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-with-ad-thumbnails/`

After uploading your plugin, if you decide to change the name just edit your primary plugin file: `Plugin Name: name of plugin` to its new name and commit the change.  Your plugin url will stay the same, but the display name will change.

Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/plugin-developer-faq/#can-i-change-my-plugins-name

Answer (score 0):

The best way to sort it is contacting: plugins@wordpress.org

I'm not sure that they'll change the url though.

Regarding name of the plugin, simply change it through the php file header and also from the readme.txt file of your plugin.